# Coded UI confused when selecting from list with identical items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

In one of my application's windows I have a list box displaying 2 records:

John Smith

John Smith

These are two different records. When I click by hand on the first John Smith record, I'm supposed to see his phone number (555-555-5555), and I do. When I click on the second John Smith record, I'm supposed to see different phone number (777-777-7777), and I do as well.

However, when I record clicking on the first item in the list, I get EXACTLY the same code as when clicking on the second item in the list (CodedUI is looking for "John Smith" item in the list by display text and then selecting it, instead of selecting an item at whatever list index I had clicked). 
Then my assertions fail when I want to verify second John Smith's phone number (777-777-7777) because CodedUI selects the first record and gets first John Smith's number (555-555-5555) instead.

How do I work around it? I need to support users who have identical names. No, I do not want to add any extra information to the first "John Smith" to make it display slightly differently than the second "John Smith".

```
    /// <summary>
    /// InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItem - Use 'InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItemParams' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItem()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinList uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList = this.UIOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsList;
        #endregion

        // Select 'John Smith' in 'listBoxOwnersRecords' list box
        uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList.SelectedItemsAsString = this.InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItemParams.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsListSelectedItemsAsString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItem - Use 'InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItemParams' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItem()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinList uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList = this.UIOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsList;
        #endregion

        // Select 'John Smith' in 'listBoxOwnersRecords' list box
        uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList.SelectedItemsAsString = this.InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItemParams.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsListSelectedItemsAsString;
    }

/// <summary>
/// Parameters to be passed into 'InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItem'
/// </summary>
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
public class InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectFirstItemParams
{

    #region Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Select 'John Smith' in 'listBoxOwnersRecords' list box
    /// </summary>
    public string UIListBoxOwnersRecordsListSelectedItemsAsString = "John Smith";
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Parameters to be passed into 'InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItem'
/// </summary>
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
public class InOwnersRecordsWindowSelectSecondItemParams
{

    #region Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Select 'John Smith' in 'listBoxOwnersRecords' list box
    /// </summary>
    public string UIListBoxOwnersRecordsListSelectedItemsAsString = "John Smith";
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this, but need to be hand-coded. Also, if you can share code of page where that list is located, it would be easier for me to help.
Asking this because you can use parent-child relations.
Let’s presume that this is standard html list with id.

```
<ul id=”list”>
<li>John Smith</li>
<li>John Smith</li>
</ul>
```

You find John Smith that you want with parent-child relation.

```
var parent = FindListById(browser, "list");
var child1 = parent.GetChildren()[0]; // this is 1st child of UL with id=list, in your case first John Smith
var child2 = parent.GetChildren()[1]; // this is 2nd child of UL with id=list, in your case second John Smith
Mouse.Click(child2);

public HtmlList FindListById(UITestControl parent, string id)
{
    var parentlist= new HtmlList(parent);
    parentlist.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlList.PropertyNames.Id, id);
    return parentlist;
}
```

If list are spans inside of div or something like that, logic is same. First find parent by some of controls (id or friendly name are the best), then search for children 
This also can be done on multiple levels.

Comment: :) Nothing wrong with hand coding ... I experienced "I can just CLICK on list item" epiphany just before reading your answer. It is a sound work-around. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with it for some time and then realized that when I select items from a list by hand, I simply CLICK on an item at particular location in the list. 
It turns out that I can do exactly the same in CodedUI code --

```
    public void InOwnersRecordsWindowClickOnListItemAtIndex(int index)
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinList uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList = this.UIOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsWindow.UIListBoxOwnersRecordsList;
        #endregion

        Mouse.Click(uIListBoxOwnersRecordsList.Items[index]);
    }
```

The above is a modified version of InOwnersRecordsWindowClickOnListItem() that gets recorded by Coded UI Test Builder when I click on a list item with a mouse. 
I had to move it to UIMap.cs so it does not get overwritten whenever new tests are added. Yes, it needs checks for out-of-bounds index values. Now I can have any number of "John Smith"s in the list and I can have CodedUI code click on any of them by simply specifying the index.

Thank you for your suggestions